# How to select attributes with respect to Information Gain in weka?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, information-retrieval, text-classification

i am working in weka for text classification. I have total of 113232 attributes in vocabulary out of which i want to select top 10, 000 attributes. Follwing is setting of my informationGain filter

```
AttributeSelection featureSelectionFilter = new AttributeSelection();

InfoGainAttributeEval informationGain = new InfoGainAttributeEval();

 Ranker ranker = new Ranker();
 ranker.setNumToSelect(10000);
 ranker.setThreshold(0);
```

I assumed that it may arrange the attributes in descending order with respect to their information gain, i am not sure i am right or wrong in my assumption here is an image of three attributes

[image]

The maximum value, std dev, mean all of first attribute is higher than other which may indicate its importance but these values for second attribute is less than 3rd ? Is it right ? How to IG select attributes from vocabulary when we set numToSelect(10, 000); ?

Comment: Information Gain is different from maximum, standard deviation, and mean. Information Gain measures the correlation between the attribute values and the class values. It is perfectly possible that an attribute has much less frequency (thus mean value) than another, and a bigger Information Gain score.

Comment: @JoseMariaGomezHidalgo thanx for passing through, Do IG filter in weka rank all the attributes in descending order or any order like IG(highest) .... IG(smallest) etc? or If i select number of attributes to 10, 000 out of 100, 000 would it select 10, 000 attributes with max IG from 100, 000 total attributes in dataset ?

Comment: Yes, it works exactly that way when using the `Ranker` search method.